# Transformation matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, matrix, interpolation

I have a scale in a 3D space from -10 to 10 with step of 2.5 (`[-10,-7.5,-5,-2.5,0,2.5,5,7.5,10]`).
I have a 3D point in this scale, I want mapped it in another 3D space from 0 to 8 with step of 1 (`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`).

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of mapping do you want ? Is it a linear mapping ? I't not realy clear what you are asking. Can you give an example with the expected result ?

Comment: So you want something like `value = value / 2.5 + 4`?

Comment: It depends on how you represent your 3D matrix. In some case, matrix multiplication with the scaling matrix would be easier, for instance using numpy. Can you give example of a few data before and after matrix transformation?

Answer (score 0):

In [this stack exachange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/178629/210498) you find the mathematical formula for normalization within a range. The python implementation could be the following:

```
def normalize(values, curr_bounds, new_bounds):
    return [(x - curr_bounds[0]) * (new_bounds[1] - new_bounds[0]) / (curr_bounds[1] - curr_bounds[0] + new_bounds[0]) for x in values]
```

Your request is not very clear, if your data needs to be mapped in a discrete range (rounded by step) then you can do this:

```
def normalize_step(values, curr_bounds, new_bounds, new_step):
    return [round_step(new_step, (x - curr_bounds[0]) * (new_bounds[1] - new_bounds[0]) / (curr_bounds[1] - curr_bounds[0] + new_bounds[0])) for x in values]

def round_step(step, n):
    return (n//step + 1) * step if n%step >= step/2 else n//step * step
```

For example, given the following data:

```
current_bounds = (-10, 10)
new_bounds = (0, 8)
step = 1

values = [-10, -2.5, 0, 7.5, 2.5]

normalize(values, current_bounds, new_bounds)
# [0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 5.0]

normalize_step(values, current_bounds, new_bounds, step)
# [0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 5.0]
```

**Note**: In this case the result is the same because your `step=1`, if we put the `step=1.5` the results change:

```
normalize_step(values, current_bounds, new_bounds, 1.5)
# [0.0, 3.0, 4.5, 7.5, 4.5]
```